Column Generation, Cycling and Degeneracy
Need some help here w.r.t Column Generation.
Assume that I have a set partitioning minimization problem. It is a crew scheduling problem.
Assume that I have all the crew pairings available with me. I do know that this is not possible for large instances but I am trying out for small instances first.
In my case the no. of pairings are 6 million so not too large.
Then I pass these pairings as LP variables to the Gurobi LP solver and retrieve the optimal LP solution. Say it is x*. The the optimal set of pairings corresponding to this obj value x* be P*.
Now consider a custom code written by me. This basically takes in an initial feasible solution, computes the LP, finds the dual values, computes the negative reduced cost of all 6 mil pairings.
Now consider the IFS input to my custom code as : the x*/P* nothing but the optimal soln itself.
Key Question : Shouldnt the reduced cost of each pairing be +ve or 0? Because we are already feeding the LP optimal solution. Why are some pairings still having -ve reduced cost? What happens is that my custom code then says "well...we have some -ve red cost pairings->add to RMP and see what happens...". So instead of terminating at iteration 0 saying no neg red cost columns found, it goes until say some iteration 50 and after 10 mins, it says optimal soln encountered.
Is the above problem called cycling? Or is it a different word in CG. More importantly, how to solve this issue?
Thanks
Yours Sincerely,
Hariharan Subramanian

"Why are some pairings still having -ve reduced cost?" either these values are very small (most solvers work with floating point arithmetic, hence numerical issues), or there is a bug in your code

One possibility comes to mind. If you have finite upper/lower bounds on variables, implemented as bounds rather than explicit constraints, you need to take into account the shadow prices (dual values) of those bounds. I posted about this a while back. Also note that the reduced cost of a bounded variable will not necessarily be 0 if the optimal solution has it at the bound (for the same reason: reduced cost = dual value of the bound).

Or if the bounds are redundant, you can just omit them.  See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/608/variable-bounds-in-column-generation

@RobPratt Right -- provided they omit them both places.
